# Reputação SO em Português Meta e SO em Português

Tags: suporte

A pontuação de reputação do Stack Overflow em Português Meta e Stack Overflow em Português não deveria ser integrada?

Por que os pontos são separados?

Comment: A pontuação exibida pelo meta é a mesma que você obteve no SOpt.

Comment: Então o que é feito aqui no meta não vale pontos?

Comment: Os votos que você recebe aqui não contam pontos para o site principal. Mas, você pode ganhar medalhas. Leia aqui, [o que é o meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3780/).

Comment: Tópico interessante: [Qual seria minha reputação no Meta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1871/3117)